# How can I cross compile a c++ application from manjaro linux to windows?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, c++, gcc, pacman

I've tried installing mingw-w64, but I keep on getting errors because the AUR package is broken and unmaintained. Nothing I've tried is working to install it, and wineg++ isn't working well for me. Is there any other way that I can cross compile a c++ application for windows? For context, I'm using manjaro linux (based on arch).

Comment: It depends what native API OS calls are made. For example, any use of the messaging/notification system would need to be rewritten, likely requiring importing classes for the Windows OS.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik
that's not what i mean, im trying to look for a way to compile my c++ application for windows. mingw-w64 didn't work out.